# Can I have dependend navigation properties in my EF Code first model

Tags: c#, .net, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, dbcontext

Let's say I have the following model

```
public class Human
{
    public int HumanId {get;set;}
    public int Gender {get;set;} // 0 = male, 1 = female

    public int? FatherId {get;set;}
    [ForeignKey("FatherId")]
    public virtual Human Father {get;set;}

    public int? MotherId {get;set;}
    [ForeignKey("MotherId")]
    public virtual Human Mother {get;set;}

    public virtual List<Human> Children {get;set;}        
}
```

Ok, this is a self referencing approach. For Father/Mother mapping I found a solution by writing this code in my DbContext class

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<Human>()
            .HasOptional(h => h.Father)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(h => h.MapKey("Father"));

        modelBuilder.Entity<Human>()
            .HasOptional(h => h.Mother)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(h => h.MapKey("Mother"));

    }
```

But I am struggeling with the Children property since it depend on a condition (the gender)
Normally I would write something like this

```
public virtual List<Human> Children
{
    get
    {
        if (this.Gender == 0)
            return Context.Humans.Where(x => x.FatherId == this.Id).ToList();
        else if (this.Gender == 1)
            return Context.Humans.Where(x => x.MotherId == this.Id).ToList();
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

But in my Model class I don't know about the context.

So what is the best approach to solve this? Currently I have a method

```
public List<Human> GetChildren(Human human) { ... }
```

in my DbContext class, but I would prefer to have it in my model. Is is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Create one more foreign key as general parent. Havent tested it, but in theory it should work

```
public class Human
{
    public int HumanId {get;set;}
    public int Gender {get;set;} // 0 = male, 1 = female

    public int ParentId { get; private set; }
    public virtual Human Parent { get; private set;}

    public int FatherId {get; private set;}
    public virtual Human Father {get; private set;}

    public int MotherId {get; private set;}
    public virtual Human Mother {get; private set;}

    public virtual List<Human> Children {get;set;}        

    public void SetParent(Human parent)
    {
        Parent = parent;
        if (parent.Gender ==0)
          Father = parent;
        else
          Mother = parent;
    }
}
```

DbContext

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{

    modelBuilder.Entity<Human>()
        .HasOptional(h => h.Father)
        .WithMany()
        .Map(h => h.MapKey("Father"));

    modelBuilder.Entity<Human>()
        .HasOptional(h => h.Mother)
        .WithMany()
        .Map(h => h.MapKey("Mother"));

    modelBuilder.Entity<Human>()
        .HasOptional(h => h.Parent)
        .WithMany(x => x.Children)
        .Map(h => h.MapKey("Parent"));

}
```

Comment: I don't know if that's what I need. A human can have two parents (Father and mother)